# Unable to stream more than 1 rtsp stream at a time using VLC command?

Tags: vlc, rtsp, libvlc, rtsp-server

I'm currently working on building a rtsp server with vlc and have successfully outputed a rtsp stream to my client. However, when I tried to start another stream on the same ip, port (just different path), I can clearly see in the log that the 2nd stream also working in the background but the client was unable to connect to it no matter what (he can still connect to the 1st one while 2 streams running simultaneously).

The command I have used:
1st stream:

```
vlc cvlc -vvv --loop --rtsp-frame-buffer-size 500000 --http-reconnect rtsp://*.*.* --sout '#transcode{acodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream1.sdp}' --sout-keep
```

2nd stream:

```
vlc cvlc -vvv --loop --rtsp-frame-buffer-size 500000 --http-reconnect rtsp://*.*.* --sout '#transcode{acodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream2.sdp}' --sout-keep
```

And the commands to consume the streams from the client:

```
vlc "rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/stream1.sdp"
vlc "rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/stream2.sdp"
```

Any suggestions would be much appriciated.

Comment: Use a different Port for second Stream

Comment: @Christoph I have tried that too, but the only port that works is 8554, if I change it to 8555 for example than it does not work at all. Even if using 2 different ports works, it is not as intended, what I want to setup is using 1 ip, 1 port only.